# jQuery UI, iFrame, Blue Image Border In IE(9)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, iframe

Right now, I have a jQuery UI pop-up dialog that reads from an external page.  This page reads from another external that has a video via flowplayer.

I'm using iframe to embed the video in the first:

```
<iframe id="iframeDonkey" width="100%" height="496" src="../../../../video/donkey-2009-02-23.html" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

To control the border, CSS:

```
iframe {
 border: 0px;
}
```

HTML (all the aforementioned pages):

```
<style>
a img { border:0 }
</style>
```

But I still see a blue border around the video preview picture in Internet Explorer.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this, but I had a similar problem in earlier versions of IE and this fixed it:

```
img 
{
   border-style:none;
}
```